# Solving the Two Body Problem Numerically in Python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python, numerical-calculus

I am following Example 2.2 in [Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students](http://www.nssc.ac.cn/wxzygx/weixin/201607/P020160718380095698873.pdf).

The equations of motion of the two bodies in inertial space are given as follows:
$$\ddot{X_1} = Gm_2\frac{X_2-X_1}{r^3},\space \ddot{Y_1} = Gm_2\frac{Y_2-Y_1}{r^3},\space \ddot{Z_1} = Gm_2\frac{Z_2-Z_1}{r^3}$$
$$\ddot{X_2} = Gm_1\frac{X_1-X_2}{r^3},\space \ddot{Y_2} = Gm_1\frac{Y_1-Y_2}{r^3},\space \ddot{Z_2} = Gm_1\frac{Z_1-Z_2}{r^3}$$

The objective is to use specified initial conditions and a numerical integrator to solve the equations numerically.

The initial conditions are:
$$y_0=[X_1^0, Y_1^0, Z_1^0, X_2^0, Y_2^0, Z_2^0, \dot{X}_1^0, \dot{Y}_1^0, \dot{Z}_1^0, \dot{X}_2^0, \dot{Y}_2^0, \dot{Z}_2^0]$$

I am using `odeint` from `scipy` in Python to integrate.
The solver requires a system of first-order ordinary differential equations. To do this, I am introducing several auxiliary variables.

$$a_1=X_1,\space a_2=Y_1,\space a_3=Z_1,\space a_4=X_2,\space a_5=Y_2,\space a_6=Z_3$$
$$a_7=\dot{X}_1, a_8=\dot{Y}_1, a_9=\dot{Z}_1, a_{10}=\dot{X}_2, a_{11}=\dot{Y}_2, a_{12}=\dot{Z}_2$$

There are now 12 first-order ODEs, two of which are:
$$\dot{a}_1=a_7,\space \dot{a}_2=a_8,\space \dot{a}_3=a_9,\space \dot{a}_4=a_{10},\space \dot{a}_5=a_{11},\space \dot{a}_6=a_{12},\space $$

$$\dot{a}_7=Gm_2\frac{a_4-a_1}{r^3},\space \dot{a}_8=Gm_2\frac{a_5-a_2}{r^3},\space \dot{a}_9=Gm_2\frac{a_6-a_3}{r^3}$$

$$\dot{a}_{10}=Gm_1\frac{a_1-a_4}{r^3},\space \dot{a}_{11}=Gm_1\frac{a_2-a_5}{r^3},\space \dot{a}_{12}=Gm_1\frac{a_3-a_6}{r^3}$$

Implementing this in Python:

```
# time array
time = np.arange(0, 480, 0.1)

# body m1 initial conditions
m1 = 10e26  # mass (kg)
r10 = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # initial position (m)
v10 = np.array([10e3, 20e3, 30e3])  # initial velocity (m/s)

# body m2 initial conditions
m2 = 10e26  # mass (kg)
r20 = np.array([3000e3, 0, 0])  # initial position (m)
v20 = np.array([0, 40e3, 0])  # initial velocity (m/s)

# magnitude of position vector from r1 to r2
r_mag = np.linalg.norm(r20 - r10)

# initial conditions
# [X1 (0), Y1 (1), Z1 (2), X2 (3), Y2 (4), Z2 (5), VX1 (6), VY1 (7), VZ1 (8), VX2 (9), VY2 (10), VZ2 (11)]
y0 = np.concatenate((r10, r20, v10, v20))

def two_body_eqm(_y, _t, _G, _m1, _m2, _r_mag):
    c0 = _y[6:12]
    c1 = _G * _m2 * ((_y[3:6] - _y[:3]) / np.power(_r_mag, 3))
    c2 = _G * _m1 * ((_y[:3] - _y[3:6]) / np.power(_r_mag, 3))
    return np.concatenate((c0, c1, c2))

y = odeint(two_body_eqm, y0, time, args=(G, m1, m2, r_mag))
```

When I plot the results the motion does not appear to be correct as indicated by the figures in the textbook.

[Plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpoYM.png)

[Textbook result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fna2.png)

Can someone give me an indication of what is wrong with my solution?

Additionally, to solve for the relative motion, I am using the following:

```
for yk in y:
    # approximate y at time t

    # extract inertial positions of body 1 and body 2
    r1 = yk[:3]
    r2 = yk[3:6]

    # determine position of centre of mass
    rg = ((m1 * r1) + (m2 * r2)) / (m1 + m2)

    # position vector from m1 to m2
    r12 = r2 - r1

    # position vector from m1 to g
    r1g = rg - r1

    # position vector from g to m1
    rg1 = r1 - rg

    # position vector from g to m2
    rg2 = r2 - rg
```

Thanks for your time.

---

[Updated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92HN.png)

Updated code:

```
def two_body_eqm(_y, _t, _G, _m1, _m2):
    r_mag = np.linalg.norm(_y[3:6] - _y[:3])
    c0 = _y[6:12]
    c1 = _G * _m2 * ((_y[3:6] - _y[:3]) / np.power(r_mag, 3))
    c2 = _G * _m1 * ((_y[:3] - _y[3:6]) / np.power(r_mag, 3))
    return np.concatenate((c0, c1, c2))

y = odeint(two_body_eqm, y0, time, args=(G, m1, m2))
```

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55282/2-body-equations-of-motion-in-3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most glaring problem is that you are not solving the gravitational equations for the 2-body problem. For that to be the case, you would have to compute `r_mag` at the start of `two_body_eqm` as the distance `norm(_y[3:6] - _y[:3])` between the two bodies.

Comment: Thanks, Lutz, I'm pretty sure that was the issue. I've updated the question to show the latest code and plot. Looks more as expected.